# Is this seal script and can someone translate this to English?

Tags: character-identification, seal

These symbols are on a vase or urn and I would like to know what they mean. It would be great if somebody can help me. I am not familiar with Chinese, so a translation to English would be great.

I tried to find a translation myself, but did not find any website that can help me with comparing the symbols to words. Only the D looking symbol, which I think would be 'Moon'.

[image: 299865375-603542438041522-6424036818289912822-n.jpg]

Comment: i recognise some characters as “子子孫孫永寳用之” 

Comment: This should be interpreted as 太師小子望作子子孫孫永寶用之. Indeed the D looking thing is 月 (*moon*) as the top right part of the character 望.

Comment: Thank you! How would that be translated to english? If I use Google translate then it gives 2 translations. How would I interpret this? 子子孫孫永寳用之
Children and grandchildren Yongbao use it 太師小子望作子子孫孫永寶用之
Taishi boy wants to be used by his descendants Sun Yongbao

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @dROOOze and @水巷孑蠻

the characters looks like:  `子子孫孫永寳用之` and it seems a copy like `西周 颂簋盖` ( refer to: https://view.inews.qq.com/a/20220421A07WF300 , the right most image. )

[image]

- 太師小子望作   it is made by Tai Shi Xiao Zi
- 子子孫孫永寶用之   hope my chidren, grandsuns keep it carefully and used it forever.

it may be more helpful if you post the full image of this `vase` or `urn`.